# Why My Service is not working with Msmq receive code

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, msmq

IDE: VS 2010, Windows service .net 4.0

I created a simple windows service, and tested this service with this code:

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\22Yardz_Pro\" + "error.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Service is working \n");
        }
        //ReceiveMsmqMessage();
    }
```

here in installer I have set

```
serviceProcessInstaller1. Account  = Local System
```

Then I have changed my code to

```
** protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\MyProj\" + "error.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Service is working \n");
        }
        ReceiveMsmqMessage();
    }

    private static void ReceiveMsmqMessage()
    {
        //string MsmqPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MsmqPath"];

        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\MyProjQ");

        System.Messaging.Message myMessage = queue.Receive();

        myMessage.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new String[] { "System.String,mscorlib" });
        string message = (myMessage.Body.ToString());
        string labelName = myMessage.Label;

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"F:\MyProj\" + "error.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Service started " + message + " \n");
        }
    }**
```

Can you tell me why my msmq code is not working, I have tested sapratly this code in working fine in winForms project also this is working in debugging mode but When I install service using cmd and after going in services.msc, when I start this service I am getting error

```
The _MsmqTesting service on local computer has started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if there are not in use by other services or programs
```

Can you suggest me what mistake I am doing??

Comment: Windows service programs are a bit special. In general, you should not do anything in an OnStart() method except for starting a thread to do the work, and then return right away to the services manager. Try looking at some tutorials on how to create Windows service programs.

Comment: A trick that is useful for testing is to create your program so that it can run both as a Windows service program and as a console program. There are a couple of tutorials on how to do this, try to Google "windows service as console application".

Answer (score 0):

Finally It worked, I put my code in Try catch block, and In catch block I have written the exception message in txt File, So got to know that my queue was not accessible for Local or system user, so I changed my queue accessibility and it worked.